# AWS Codepipeline: in action 'Source' is not available in region 'EU_WEST_3'

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I got a sample AWS codepipeline working in Paris region ("eu-west-3") via the console but need to get it set up via Terraform. I have one major problem :

Error: Error creating CodePipeline: InvalidActionDeclarationException: ActionType (Category: 'Source', Provider: 'Bitbucket', Owner: 'ThirdParty', Version: '1') in action 'Source' is not available in region 'EU_WEST_3'
│
│   with module.codepipeline.aws_codepipeline.codepipeline,
│   on ..\dentinnov-infra\modules\deploy\codepipeline\resources.tf line 8, in resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline":
│    8: resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {

This is my TF code :

```
# codepipeline role : (note code pipeline policy already defined in s3 module)
resource "aws_iam_role" "codepipeline" {
  name                    = var.codepipeline_role_name
  assume_role_policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.codepipeline.json
}

# Provides a CodePipeline for frontend deploy
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  name                    = var.codepipeline_name
  role_arn                = aws_iam_role.codepipeline.arn
  
  artifact_store {                              
    location              = var.location[0]     
    type                  = var.artifact_store_type
  }
  
  stage {
    name = "Source"
    action {
      name                = var.source_name
      region              = var.region
      category            = var.source_category 
      owner               = var.source_owner
      provider            = var.source_provider
      version             = var.source_version
      output_artifacts    = var.source_outArtifacts

      configuration = {
        ConnectionArn     = aws_codestarconnections_connection.connect.arn
        fullRepositoryId  = var.fullRepositoryId
        branchName        = var.branch_name
      }
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    action {
      name                = var.build_name
      region              = var.region
      category            = var.build_category
      owner               = var.build_owner
      provider            = var.build_provider
      input_artifacts     = var.build_InArtifacts
      output_artifacts    = var.build_OutArtifacts
      version             = var.build_version
      configuration = {
        ProjectName       = var.build_project_name
      }
    }
  }
 
  stage {
    name                  = "Deploy"
    action {
      name                = var.deploy_name
      region              = var.region
      category            = var.deploy_category
      owner               = var.deploy_owner
      provider            = var.deploy_provider
      input_artifacts     = var.deploy_InArtifacts
      version             = var.deploy_version     
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_codestarconnections_connection" "connect" {
  name                    = var.source_connection
  provider_type           = var.source_provider
}
```

Those are my variables

```
codepipeline_name       = "codepipeline.name"
codepipeline_role_name  = "codepipeline-frontend-role"
artifact_store_type     = "S3"

source_name             = "Source"
source_category         = "Source"
source_owner            = "ThirdParty"
source_provider         = "Bitbucket"
source_version          = "1"
source_outArtifacts     = ["source_artifact"]
source_connection       = "connect-bitbucket"
fullRepositoryId        = "reponame/frontend" 
branch_name             = "develop"

build_name              = "Build"
build_category          = "Build"
build_owner             = "AWS"
build_provider          = "CodeBuild"
build_InArtifacts       = ["source_artifact"]
build_OutArtifacts      = ["build_artifact"]
build_version           = "1"
build_project_name      = "build-frontend"

deploy_name              = "Deploy"
deploy_category          = "Deploy"
deploy_owner             = "AWS"
deploy_provider          = "CodeDeploy"
deploy_InArtifacts       = ["build_artifact"]
deploy_version           = "1"
```

Comment: What is your full TF code creating the pipeline along with all the variables.

Comment: Hello Marcin, I posted the inputs and variables. Thanks

Comment: Hello Marcin, I have updated the question and added TF code

Comment: seems issue with provider. If I put them as  `source_provider  = "GitHubEnterpriseServer" `  then the issue is not showing. When I put again `source_provider = "Bitbucket"` then issue again occured. What is wrong here ?

Comment: The issue is only with `EU_WEST_3`? Did you check if other regions work?

Comment: I tried with other regions but it generating a lot of issues because all my other resources are already created in `EU_WEST_3`. It's required a lot of changes.

Comment: Hello, someone can help to say what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Use provider = "CodeStarSourceConnection"
owner        = "AWS"

in CodePipeline Block.

Note: A connection created through AWS CloudFormation is in PENDING status by default. You can make its status AVAILABLE by updating the connection in the console.